# Why does Python's sorted() method not reverse orders of keys with the same value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I was working through some old Advent of Code problems in preparation for this year's when I came across the following oddity. Let's say we have the following Python dictionary:

```
d = {'a':5, 'b':4, 'c':4, 'd':2, 'e':3, 'f':1}
```

If we sort this dictionary by its keys, we get the following:

```
>>>print(sorted(d, key=d.get))
['f','e','d','c','b','a']
```

Now, if we try to reverse this order, we get the following:

```
>>>print(sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True))
['a','c','b','d','e','f']
```

This raised two question to me:

1. Why does the original sort by keys list `c` before `b` despite the fact that when traversing the dictionary, the first time it sees `4` is with the key `b`?
2. Why does the reversed order keep this ordering rather than reversing the order of the keys found in the original sort?

I'm sure there are other ways to solve this problem, but now I'm curious as to what the mechanics of the `sorted` method are that are causing this.

Comment: I get `['f', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'c', 'a']` and then `['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'f']`

Comment: @mathsman I suppose `'e'` (value `3`) appearing before `'d'` (value `2`)  in your first sort is a typo? That would not make any sense regardless of the Python version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`reverse=True` doesn't mean sort the input and then reverse it. `reverse=True` [means](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) reverse the *comparison results*:

> reverse is a boolean value. If set to True, then the list elements are sorted as if each comparison were reversed.

The sort is still stable, so elements equal in comparison order are kept in the order they appeared in the input.

---

Now, you might think, hey, 'c' wasn't before 'b' in the input! That means you must be on a Python version where dicts don't preserve insertion order, so the dict's order isn't the order you wrote the items in your source code. The order `sorted` saw its input was essentially arbitrary. If you want an order-preserving dict, you'll have to use a newer Python or `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! However, this brings me back to the first question: why is the first element appearing in the list c and not b? For some perspective, the behavior I want is to keep the same order as the original comparisons, but also for the keys to appear in the order they appear in the dictionary.

Comment: @mathsman: See expanded answer. (It doesn't show up as edited because the edit was in the grace period, and before your comment.) (Well, now it shows up as edited, because I edited it some more.)

Comment: Gotcha. I suppose it didn't occur to me that it might be a version issue because I'm having the issue with Python 3.5.3. I suppose I'll have to use `collections.OrderedDict` instead. Thank you again for the help!